# Make a separate legend for a ggplot2 bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I did a bar plot of my data using ggplot. Since I have too many different layers on the y axis, the default legend would be too big... Moreover, I don't like the ggplot default legend. So I want to make a separate legend and then merge the two tiff files in photoshop. 
I tried using `legend()` in this way:

```
cols <- c("#6a152d","#7229dc","#c13df1","#2f2718","#11b34f","#3ba3aa","#c49b55","#73aed2","#dc6396","#85bf0d","#1de4bb","#b6e60a","#2609a3","#022b42","#c6075b","#d34913","#1f0ba1","#02531f","#4f0351","#ef929a","#027993","#369183","#c92413","#feb306","#70d68f","#646c60","#060423","#95faa3","#445f17","#f9b0a0","#4dd092","#5a5231","#0e31b0","#f5890b","#ffecc0","#a5fdaf","#b9dced","#a973f6","#25003a","#b63156")
legend("topright",fill=cols,legend=c('g__Actinomyces','g__Atopobium','g__Corynebacterium','g__Rothia','g__Porphyromonas','g__Prevotella','g__Capnocytophaga','g__Abiotrophia','g__Granulicatella','g__Gemella','g__Streptococcus','ClostridialesFamilyXI.IncertaeSedis','CMogibacterium','Lachnospiraceae','Clostridia','Oribacterium','Peptostreptococcus','Veillonellaceae','Veillonella','Fusobacterium','Leptotrichia','Neisseria','Haemophilus','SR1','TM73','Bulleidia','Bacteroidia','Tannerella','Flavobacteriaceae','Bacilli','Clostridia','Eubacterium','Moryella','Selenomonas','Fusobacteriaceae','Campylobacter','g__Actinobacillus','Lautropia','Lactobacillus','Staphylococcus'))
```

But it returns an error:

```
Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : plot.new has not been called yet
```

The same error occurs also if I call the `ggplot()` before or if I call `par()`...

Is there a way to make only a legend box (like the `legend()` output) in ggplot2?

Thanks!

Comment: See [`scale_fill_manual`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_manual.html), [`guide_legend`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guide_legend.html).

Comment: But in both ways I can just add the legend to the plot... How can I get a separate legen (without calling the plot before)?

Comment: In `ggplot` I think you need to create a plot with the desired legend, then extract the legend as a grob. See e.g. [**here**](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs).